# Best resources for learning AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web

I am more of a jQuery developer. I find it really hard to migrate from jQuery to AngularJS. Is there any good book or online material from where I can start my ng journey?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "think in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Am looking for a good book to start with.. @Juhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting with this [article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/how-to-learn-angular.html) from ng-newsletter.
They provide a great overview about AngularJS features and if you want to deepen your knowledge regarding some feature in particular it is also provided some links and other articles for further reading.

Comment: The article is really good!